# Make a working jQuery button inside Mustache.js template

Tags: jquery, mustache

I'm using Mustache.js for a project, but I'm stuck trying to include a jQuery button inside a template.

I made a template to display the five candidates for my state's governor election. In a JSON, I included their name, photo and party affiliation. I load the data into this template:

```
{{ #governor }}
    <div class="cand-{{ head }}">
        <div class="head">
            <img src="{{ picture }}">
        </div>
        <div class="bio">
            <h5>{{ name }}</h5>
                <i class='fa fa-circle' style='color: {{ color }}'></i> {{ party }}<br>  
        </div>
    </div>
{{ /governor }}
```

Now, I want to include a jQuery button underneath the party line that will hide the other candidates and bring up a div with details that will close with another button nested within. However, the button doesn't work inside the Mustache template. It works fine outside. Here's my button code:

```
<button class="open-govA">Details</button>

<script>
$( ".open-govA" ).click(function() {
  $( ".details-govA" ).show( "slow" );
  $( ".cand-govB, .cand-govC, .cand-govD, .cand-govE").hide( "slow" );
  });

$( ".close-govA" ).click(function() {
  $( ".details-gov" ).hide( "slow" );
   $( ".cand-govB, .cand-govC, .cand-govD, .cand-govE").show( "slow" );
  });
</script>
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: use event delegation for dynamically created elements. This issue gets asked numerous times a day ... should be easy web search

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Keep in mind the template is within <script> tags. I think that has something to do with the button and the jQuery code not working.

Comment: yes it definitely does and you need to use `on()` and delegate those events. google `jquery event delegation`

Comment: Still struggling. I've researched jQuery event delegation and couldn't find anything about putting a button in a script template. I tried on(), but it only works with a button outside the template.

Comment: must not be using `on()` correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everybody already said, you should use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on) with [the jQuery `on` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
<script>
  $( "#parentInPage" ).on("click", ".open-govA", function() {
    $( ".details-govA" ).show( "slow" );
    $( ".cand-govB, .cand-govC, .cand-govD, .cand-govE").hide( "slow" );
  });

  $( "#parentInPage" ).on("click", ".close-govA", function() {
    $( ".details-gov" ).hide( "slow" );
    $( ".cand-govB, .cand-govC, .cand-govD, .cand-govE").show( "slow" );
  });
</script>
```

In case you don't have a common element on the page where you append all those templates, you can use `"body"`. Just be careful with an eccessive use of that - see the **Event Performance** section on the jQuery `on`o documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I found out I wasn't using the right #parentInPage value.